# while loop just randomly stopped working for no reason?

Tags: python, while-loop

I am currently writing my first program in Python which is basically a vocabulary learning game but for some reason i am suddenly having some trouble with a while loop in one function that has first been working just fine, than it started working badly (breaking too late) and now just doesn't work at all. I've been searching all the internet and my code thoroughly but I seriously can't find anything. Just doesn't make any sense.

```
def Spiel_Spanisch_Deutsch():
    puntos = 0
    intentos = 0

    while puntos < 20:
        for vokabel in vokabeln:
            antwort = input(vokabel.spanisch + ": ")
            if antwort == vokabel.deutsch:
                print("Corecto! {} = {}\n".format(vokabel.spanisch, vokabel.deutsch))
                puntos += 1
                intentos += 1
                print("Tienes {} de 20 puntos!\n ".format(puntos))
            else:
                print("Falso! Estudia mejor! La corecta respuensa seria: {}\n".format(vokabel.deutsch))
                intentos += 1
                print("Tienes {} de 20 puntos!\n ".format(puntos))
    print("You needed {} tries to get 20 right!\n".format(intentos)
```

The while loop just won't break when the variable puntos > 20 but apparently the point counter works and the value is increasing because in the text that i'm printing the score increases. Thank u!

Comment: It's not stopping *randomly*, it's stopping *unexpectedly*. I suggest you step through your code in the debugger and examine the values of the variables in order to determine where the problem lies.

Comment: have print to the counter and verify that if it reaches 20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
while puntos < 20:
    for vokabel in vokabeln:
        antwort = input(vokabel.spanisch + ": ")
        # Irrelevant code removed.
```

If the problem is that it's not stopping as soon as you reach the required number of puntos (points), you should realise that the outer loop cannot exit while the inner loop is still running. The outer loop check is only done *after* each inner loop completes (the *whole* inner loop, not just one iteration).

For example, let's say `vokabeln` (vocabulary?) has fifteen items in it and you're a perfect translator, so will get everything right.

The first iteration of the outer loop will therefore end up with `puntos == 15`.

It will then enter the second iteration of that outer loop and ask you the ***full fifteen questions*** in the inner loop, even though you will have reached 20 points after answering the first five.

> As an aside, if it stopped working for no apparent reason, it may be because your original `vokabeln` had `n` entries, where `n` is a factor of twenty (i.e., 1, 2, 4, 5, 10), or you were getting enough wrong so that the end of the inner loop happened to coincide with the answer that gave you your twentieth point.

If you want to stop immediately after getting enough right answers, you can use something like:

```py
def Spiel_Spanisch_Deutsch():
    puntos = 0
    intentos = 0
    necesitar = 20      # My very suspect attempt at Spanish :-)

    while puntos < necesitar:
        for vokabel in vokabeln:
            antwort = input(vokabel.spanisch + ": ")
            if antwort == vokabel.deutsch:
                print(f"Corecto! {vokabel.spanisch} = {vokabel.deutsch}")
                puntos += 1
            else:
                print(f"Falso! Estudia mejor! La corecta respuensa seria: {vokabel.deutsch}")

            intentos += 1
            print(f"Tienes {puntos} de {necesitar} puntos!")

            # Exit inner loop as soon as we answer what's required.

            if puntos >= necesitar: break

    print(f"You needed {intentos} tries to get {necesitar} right!")
```

I've also cleaned up the code a little so as not to duplicate things like incrementing `intentos` (attempts?).

I've used f-strings (Python 3.6+) since they're *much* better than `str.format()` in that the thing you're printing is *exactly* in the output string where you want to print it. You don't have to go searching for it in the `str.format()` argument list if you want to change it or figure out where it comes from.